# Java index out of bounds error

Tags: java, runtime-error, indexoutofboundsexception

I am writing the code in Java as a plugin to a Minecraft server, but the logical principles are general in nature.

```
public void doReviewMember(CommandSender playerSent) {
    if (!reviewsMember.isEmpty()) {
        Review doThis = null;

        ArrayList<Review> players = new ArrayList<Review>();
        ArrayList<Review> playersVIP = new ArrayList<Review>();
        ArrayList<Review> playersVIPplus = new ArrayList<Review>();

        for (int c1 = 0; c1 < reviewsMember.size(); c1++) {
            if  (Bukkit.getPlayer(reviewsMember.get(c1).getName()).hasPermission("reviewplugin.vipplus"))
                playersVIPplus.add(reviewsMember.get(c1));
            else if (Bukkit.getPlayer(reviewsMember.get(c1).getName()).hasPermission("reviewplugin.vip"))
                playersVIP.add(reviewsMember.get(c1));
            else players.add(reviewsMember.get(c1));
        }

        if (playersVIPplus.size() > 0)
            doThis = playersVIPplus.get(0);
        else if (playersVIP.size() > 0)
            doThis = playersVIP.get(0);
        else doThis = players.get(0);

        Bukkit.getPlayer(playerSent.getName()).sendMessage("§4[§6ReviewPlugin§4] §eThis review is for §b" + doThis.getName());
        Bukkit.getPlayer(playerSent.getName()).teleport(doThis.getLocation());
        reviewsMember.remove(doThis);
        if (reviewsMember.size() > 1)
            Bukkit.getPlayer(playerSent.getName()).sendMessage("§4[§6ReviewPlugin§4] §eThere are " + reviewsMember.size() + " member reviews left to do.");
        else if (reviewsMember.size() == 1)
            Bukkit.getPlayer(playerSent.getName()).sendMessage("§4[§6ReviewPlugin§4] §eThere is " + reviewsMember.size() + " member review left to do.");
        else
            Bukkit.getPlayer(playerSent.getName()).sendMessage("§4[§6ReviewPlugin§4] §eThere are no more Member reviews to do at this time!");
    }
    else {
        Bukkit.getPlayer(playerSent.getName()).sendMessage("§4[§6ReviewPlugin§4] §eThere are no more Member reviews to do at this time!");
    }
}
```

The index out of bounds error was occurring in the for loop, so I have no idea where I am going wrong. This was tested w/o error on a Windows 8 machine but when implemented into a Linux it failed every time with the index out of bounds error.

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace? Error is probably deeper.

Comment: Have you inserted print statements to show the state of the variables at various points and to see exactly where the error is occurring?

Comment: Unrelated hint: try to make your code easier to work with and faster by extracting some local variables: `Review review = reviewsMember.get(c1); Player player = Bukkit.getPlayer(review.getName());` etc.

Answer (score 0):

The above code cannot fail *unless* some background thread modifies the array in the middle of the loop. Which is most likely the reason for your problem.